# shell script execute background but can not find

Tags: shell, process

I made shell script
this shell script name is torrent_alert

This code  "for" infinity loop execute every 10 second(sleep 10)
So I execute this script background

a few days ago I can find my script on process list use this command

```
ps ax | grep torrent_alert
```

But since yesterday I can't find my script is working or not working
I try to reboot, but it doesn't help me

So my question is I want to know my script is alive or dead and process number

How can I solve this problem?

P.S. I use script in Ubuntu